# How to get read receipts in Codeigniter Using GMail SMTP?

Tags: codeigniter, smtp

I want to add read receipts function on email send using GMail smtp in Codeigniter. How can I do that? I searched in google and it's only have for pure PHP Mail Function and PHPMailer. But i don't want to use phpmailer plugin. So help me to do with Codeigniter Mail function. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the CodeIgniter function to add some extra header in your email:

with `Read-Receipt-To:` , `X-Confirm-reading-to:` or `Disposition-Notification-To:` headers and you put your email or your compagny name followed by your email for the value.
The fonction is `$this->email->set_header($header, $value);`

But be careful, it doesn't works everytime because of web services security boxes, sometimes they don't let these headers to return to the value's email adress put.